# counting and printing from an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have an assignment to create a tic tac toe board and filling the board with X, O or a space using Random. After the array is filled I have to use a method to count each X or O in each row of the method, Ex. Row 1 has 2 X's and 1 O. I have already filled the array but I don't know how to use a for loop to count the amount of X's or O's in each row of the array. After I do rows I also have to do columns and Diagonals so ignore those methods for now, Thanks

```
public class Arrayexample {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int size;
        char array[][]; 
        Random randy = new Random();
        for (size = 4; size <= 4; size++)
        {
            //create array
            array = fillArray(size, randy);
            printArray(array);
            doRows(array);
            doColumns(array);
            doDiagonals(array);
            //print array
            System.out.println("\n\t\tsize " + size); 
        }
    }

    static char [][] fillArray (int size, Random randy)
    {
        int row,col,N;
        char array[][];
        // create array
        array = new char[size][size];
        //code inside loops to choose X, O or space with weighting
        for(row=0;row<array.length;row++)
        {
            for (col=0;col<array.length;col++)
            {
                N = randy.nextInt(5);
                array[row][col] =
                N == 0 || N == 1 ? 'X' : N == 2 || N == 3 ? 'O' : ' ';
            }
        }
        return array;
    }    

    static void printArray (char a [][])
    { 
        int row, col;        
        for(row=0; row < a.length; row++) {
            for(col=0; col < a[0].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(a[row][col] +" " );
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
    static void doRows (char a [][])
    {
        int [][] counts; 
        counts = new int [2][2]; 
        getRows(a,counts); 
        printRows(a,counts); 
    }    
    static void getRows (char a [][], int counts [][])
    {
        int row,countsRow; 
        for(row=0; row < a.length; row++)
        {
            for (countsRow =0; countsRow<a.length; countsRow++)
            {

            }    
            System.out.println("row " + (row + 1)); 
        }
    }
    static void printRows (char a [][], int counts [][])
    {

    }

    static void doColumns (char a [][])
    {
        int counts [][]; 
        counts = new int [2][2];
        getColumns(a,counts); 
        printColumns(a,counts); 
    }

    static void getColumns (char a [][], int counts [][])
    {
        int col, countsCol; 
        for (countsCol = 0; countsCol<a.length; countsCol ++ )
        {

        }
    }

    static void printColumns (char a [][], int counts [][])
    {

    }

    static void doDiagonals(char a [][])
    {
        int counts [][];    
        counts = new int [2][2];
        getDiagonals(a,counts); 
        printDiagonals(a,counts); 

    }

    static void getDiagonals(char a [][], int counts [][])
    {

    }

    static void printDiagonals (char a [][], int counts [][])
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Question is very ambiguous. Code presented is not OOP designed in the least, even though it is written in Java. If you wish for someone to be able to answer you (such as myself), it is best to write, simple, legible code that follows common practices, such as semi-standard indentation, method headers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for rows and adapt to the others:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    int countX = 0;
    int countO = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
           if(array[i][j] == 'X')
            countX++;
        else
            countO++;
    }
    System.out.println("row: " + i + " " + countX + "X " + countO + "O");
}
```

Comment: When I implemented your code the first row prints right but after that the rows add the previous row to the current row. Ex. row 1 XOX, row 2 XOX, so when row 2 prints its says 4 X's and 2 Os  and not 2 X's and 1 O

Comment: Check if you put int countX = 0 and int countY = 0 inside of first loop, so the vars are always 0 for each row.